# How to define a relation between three tables and a junction table

Tags: yii2

Ok, I'm new to yii2 (and web development, as a matter of fact) so take it easy on me.

If I had a many-to-many relation between two tables, say, Environment and Category, and a junction table relEnvCat, I would have something like this:

```
public function getEnvironments()
{
        return $this->hasMany(ENVIRONMENT::className(), ['PKENVIRONMENT' => 'FKENVIRONMENT'])
                    ->viaTable('RELENVCAT', ['FKCATEGORY' => 'PKCATEGORY']);
}
```

But what should I do if I had three tables and a junction table. Exemple with their primary keys: CI(pkCi), Environment(pkEnvironment)and Context(pkContext).

Then I have a junction table, named relCiEnvCont with these foreign keys (fkCI, fkEnvironment, fkContext).

But, I don't know how to define this triple relation on yii... Can anybody help me?

As far as I know, which isn't much, all I can do is this:

```
class CI extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
....
public function getRELCIENVCONTs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RELCIENVCONT::className(), ['FKCI' => 'PKCI']);
    }
...
}
```

And that is not good at all... I'm thinking maybe these relations are far too complex for Active Records and I should ditch it and use query builder instead?